# Alternative for procedure concept in Vertica DB

Tags: vertica

My Scenario:

I have a table in Vertica with 1000 records loaded on particular day say Day 1. 
Let the key column be Id .

I need to fake data similarly for 100 days , 1000 records each per day with unique values for the key columnID , for each day.

I heard it is impossible to create procedure in Vertica to do repetitive tasks .

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you just attempting to replicate your existing data or are you trying to get stored procedure functionality like in a RDBMS?

Comment: The question is indeed unclear, but even if Vertica does not have stored procedure, it has odbc/jdbc connectors, so whatever you cannot do inside Vertica that way could be done in python/java or whatever you are familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Vertica does not support Stored Procedures as you have in some DBs.  Instead it has User Defined Functions.  You write them in Java or whatever but it runs INSIDE the database as if it were an SP.  (it also supports External Procedures to run stuff outside the DB but I don't think that's what you want)